# ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to learn Hadoop version 1.1.0 on HDInsights. I followed step by step instructions to run the commands on the Hadoop Command line. I first compiled the java code and then created a jar file and then executed the map reduce command. But when I run the mapreduce command, it gives me the error below. Can someone help me understand what the error means and what I need to do to correct it?

```
c:\hadoop-training\mrdcache>hadoop jar DCache.jar DCache mrdcache/input/nyse mrdcache/output

13/08/08 23:29:01 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/08/08 23:29:01 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://localhost:8020/hadoop/hdfs/tmp/mapred/staging/Ramya/.staging/job_201308082321_0001
13/08/08 23:29:01 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:myusername cause:java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: mrdcache/output Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: mrdcache/output
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:518)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache.getFileStatus(DistributedCache.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:750)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobClient.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobClient.java:655)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$300(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:865)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1261)
    at DCache.main(Dcache.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Appreciate any help! 
Thanks,
Ramya

Comment: Do yo u have the permission to access `mrdcache/output` it (the user running the map-reduce code)

Comment: yes i do.. I am running it as an administrator..

Answer (score 0):

Where is the file? you should use ASV like this:
 hadoop jar C:\Tutorials\log4jMapReduce.jar log4jMapReduce asv:///sample.log asv:///Tutorials/output

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/using-mapreduce-with-hdinsight/

Comment: If all you're doing is linking to an external site, please put that in a comment rather than as an answer